# How can i position a div at right?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

1
      2
      3

```
<div class="search-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-input background-secondary">
</div>
```

How can i can the      to set it at right of the screen

Answer (score -4):

set parent div's css as following:

```
display: flex;
justify-content:end;
```

Comment: What's wrong in this?